# Clear search box value by button click

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using one search box.How to clear value of this text box By button click.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".searchClear").click(function(){
           //document.getElementById("searchGo").value="";
           $('#searchGo').removeAttr('value');
       });
```

```html
<input class="col-lg-3" type="text" name="searchroleName" id="searchroleName">
    <button class="btn searchGo" id="searchGo">Go</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn searchClear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".searchClear").click(function(){
           $('#searchroleName').val(' ');
       });

Comment: @DhavalMarthak No not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".searchClear").click(function(){
           $('#searchroleName').val('');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty the value rather than removing the element attribute, Also your brackets are not closed properly.

Also the selector of an input is wrong.

Try following code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".searchClear").click(function() {
     //document.getElementById("searchGo").value="";
     $('#searchroleName').val("");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="col-lg-3" type="text" name="searchroleName" id="searchroleName">
<button class="btn searchGo" id="searchGo">Go</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn searchClear">Clear</button>
```